# Customise Mac Terminal command Control+w

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I am trying to find a way to customise Mac Terminal command:**Control+w** which can also consider delimiters like **=**, **-**. Currently **Space** is only way it considers. For example for the command

`$foo --option=foos`

If I use Control+w, it deletes **--option=foos** but I want it to delete firstly till **=**, then next delimiter identified, if I pass command once more

Comment: Even I had same question in mind. It would be very helpful if someone can answer this question. Thanks Samudrala